# Devise 'Unpermitted parameter: email' can't sign in Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-admin

I'm using `devise` with `cancancan` and `rails_admin`. On signing in the `admin` model, I get the following error.

`Unpermitted parameter: email`

`admin` model was generated by `devise` using `rails g devise Admin`

I tried overriding the controller and here's my `admin/registrations_conroller.rb`

```
class Admin::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

      protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:email)
        if params[:action] == 'update'
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { 
            |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
          }
        elsif params[:action] == 'create'
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { 
            |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
          }
        end
      end
      # def new
      #   super
      # end

      # def create
      #   super
      # end
    end
```

Here's my `admin` model

```
   class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      validates :email, presence: true

    end
```

My `ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(admin)
    admin ||= Admin.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if admin.position? :superadmin
        can :manage, :all
    else
        can :read
    end
   end
end
```

My `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ## == Devise ==
   config.authenticate_with do
     warden.authenticate! scope: :admin
   end
   config.current_user_method(&:current_admin)

  ## == Cancan ==
  config.authorize_with :cancan
  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end
end
```

And finally my `admins` table

```
create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "position"
end
```

What I'm trying to do is have a `position` column in the `admins` table which specifies the type of admin i.e. `superadmin`, `moderator` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should us directly admin/registrations_conroller.rb

```
 class Admin::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
    end
```

Comment: Still unable to login. Here's what the debugger says
--- !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
elements:
  utf8: "✓"
  authenticity_token: 9lfnKwkGdiBBUi72F+EJb+3um31IO8v9epWG76193Gy5FVU/36S26I8V8YyCjzGW/RkT4LmisAYLUcfBkAsiSw==
  admin: !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
    elements:
      email: test@test.com
      password: password
      remember_me: '0'
    ivars:
      :@permitted: false
  commit: Log in
  controller: devise/sessions
  action: create
ivars:
  :@permitted: false

And the console says `Unpermitted parameter: email`